# How can I get the list of pages a Page likes (fanned pages)?

Tags: web-applications, facebook-like, facebook-page

In a Facebook page (i.e. Page XYZ), one of the elements in the timeline is the Likes box, showing the pages that XYZ likes. There is usually a link to "See all" in this box, where you can see the list of all pages (the link directs to: https://www.facebook.com/browse/fanned_pages/?id=xxx)

Which field/connection of the API should I use to retrieve this list of pages?
I looked it up in the API docs and could not find the field/connection I should use to get this.

Thanks very much,
Gustavo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure it's in the docs, but it's a call to 
`/<PAGE ID>/likes` using an access token, 
it returns the list of things that `<PAGE ID>` likes in JSON format with the name, ID and category of the page

Example: `https://graph.facebook.com/278905338821044/likes?access_token=<ACCESS TOKEN>`

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "category": "Internet/software", 
      "name": "Facebook Security", 
      "id": "31987371885"
    }, 
 // removed the rest
}
```

Comment: It worked, awesome, so simple. I wonder why this isn't in the docs, though. Thanks.

Comment: I am getting empty object please help me.

Comment: You're probably missing the correct permissions: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/ or aren't using a Page access token